# jquery accordion input[text] maxlength bug update on Firefox, please confirm

Tags: jquery, firefox, jquery-ui-accordion

When i use accordion feature in two panels and try to set maxlength of an input field by using a js function in other panel, the maxlength value changes in mozilla Firefox in value (i checked via firebug) however it does not change on the field (you can not edit).

```
It works fine for chrome but not Firefox. Is this a real bug and what is the solution?
```

You can see the bug in detail:
http://jsfiddle.net/Jc3uc/1/

To see error: 
at start the maxlength sets to 4.
when you open second tab and click the link it aims to set it to 45. however the maxlength value changes but you can not edit the field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reported the same problem to http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8879 ..  It seems that the case occurs using Firefox4, and there is no solution for that for the time being. Since its due to bug in Firefox, check https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=818270

Be aware of that case when using accordion

Answer (score 0):

yes it does appear top be a quirk with jQuery and firefox as well as some other browsers.

One way to work around it is to just replace the element with a new one:

```
function xy(txv) {
    $('#tx2').replaceWith('<input id="tx2" type="text" size="35" name="txl"  maxlength="45" >').val(txv.test);
    $('#tx1').html('Email:')
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QrzjU/

Comment: it does not work in this form, one can make it assigning the value after replacement. However it also loses its bond actions.

Comment: then rebind it when you create it. Or are these bindings on the codebehind? If you they are client bindings show them in your fiddle and I can update mine to show you where to rebind them.

Comment: restoring the element and rebinding the events seems to be the only solution.

Comment: so you were able to rebind them then? I am glad to hear.